# Is there a way to create a grid?

Tags: python, grid

Is there a way to create a grid which i can access easy?
For example if the grid is:

```
x y z
1 2 3
a b c
```

And if i run:
`print([1][1])`
It would output 2

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to use nested lists:

```
grid = [['x', 'y', 'z'], [1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Comment: Just to be clear to print the vaule at 1,1 you would use `print(grid[1][1])` not `print([1][1])`

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if you have (or could have) `numpy` installed, is a 2-D [`numpy.ndarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([['x', 'y', 'z'], 
                  [1, 2, 3], 
                  ['a', 'b', 'c']], 
                 dtype=object)
>>> a
array([[x, y, z],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [a, b, c]], dtype=object)
```

Although this takes a bit more set-up, it allows a slightly simpler indexing syntax:

```
>>> a[1, 1]
2
```

and a great deal of additional functionality.